# Switching from SoundPlayer to Windows Media Player Video

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-media-player, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have a paradigm which plays audio stimuli followed by images of the stimuli to be selected by the user. I need to replace the audio stimuli with video.  Here is the  original session code/implementation of the paradigm. At the end is one of my failed attempts at editing the session code that freezes trying to play. I could not fit all of the code, please let me know what else I should add of use.

Session:

```
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Media;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    namespace Memory
    {
/// <summary>
/// this handles the creation, tracking, and scoring of a single session
/// </summary>
class Session
{
    #region class Vars/Properties
    File save;
    ItemsPool _all, _presented, _selected, _displayed;
    initVars Vars = initVars.defaults;
    sessTimer _timer;
    System.Timers.Timer onset;
    bool p_onset = false;
    string _output = "Memdata." + DateTime.Now.ToString("Mdyy-HHmm") + ".txt";
    int _sessCount = 0;
    SoundPlayer player;
    /// <summary>
    /// a collection of the sum of the scores for this session
    /// </summary>
    List<int[]> ScoreSum;
    /// <summary>
    /// the Sum of time results
    /// </summary>
    int TimesSum = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// the number of items to display
    /// </summary>
    int _itemCount;
    /// <summary>
    /// the number of items to display
    /// </summary>
    public int itemCount
    {
        get { return _itemCount; }
        set { _itemCount = value; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// the session count
    /// </summary>
    public int SessionCount { get { return _sessCount; } }
    string _prefix = "";
    /// <summary>
    /// the prefix for the Rows
    /// </summary>
    public string RowPrefix
    {
        get { return _prefix; }
        set { _prefix = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// the image width for each item
    /// </summary>
    public int ImgWidth { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// the max runs for this session
    /// </summary>
    public int maxRuns { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// debug value
    /// </summary>
    public bool debug { get { return Vars.debug; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// the onset value
    /// </summary>
    public int onsetValue { get { return Vars.onset; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// view Images before Audio
    /// </summary>
    public bool ViewImages { get { return Vars.ViewImages; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// allow correction 
    /// </summary>
    public bool AllowCorrection { get { return Vars.allowCorrection; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// play sounds one at a time
    /// </summary>
    public bool playOne { get { return Vars.playOne; } }
    #endregion

    #region constructors
    /// <summary>
    /// create a new session and load settings from an XML string or file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xml">either a path or a string of XML</param>
    /// <param name="SaveName">the name of the output file</param>
    public Session(string xml, string output, bool makeUnique)
    {
        if (output != "")
        { _output = output; }
        save = new File(_output);
        if (makeUnique)
        { save.MakeUnique(); }

        XDocument setupXML;
        //check to see if there are any XML nodes ie. is this a string of XML, or a path
        string fchar = xml.Substring(0, 1);
        if (fchar == "<")
        { setupXML = XDocument.Parse(xml); }
        else
        { setupXML = XDocument.Load(xml); }

        LoadXML(setupXML);
        //set some class vars based on the initial vars
        //these are variables that may change during the session
        _itemCount = Vars.Columns;
        ScoreSum = new List<int[]>();

        ImgWidth = Vars.width;
        maxRuns = Vars.maxRuns;

        _presented = new ItemsPool();
        _selected = new ItemsPool();

        _timer = new sessTimer();
        _timer.Update += new EventHandler<StringEventArgs>(_timer_Update);

    }
    void LoadXML(XDocument setupXML)
    { 
        // get the initial variables
        var initVars = from feed in setupXML.Descendants("var")
                       select new
                       {
                           Name = feed.Attribute("Name").Value,
                           Value = feed.Value
                       };
        foreach (var feed in initVars)
        { Vars.SetVar(feed.Name, feed.Value); }

        // parse the image and audio filename
        var ifiles = from feed in setupXML.Descendants("stim")
                     select new Item 
                     {
                         Name = feed.Attribute("Name").Value,
                         audio = feed.Element("audio").Value,
                         image = feed.Element("image").Value
                     };

        _all = new ItemsPool();
        foreach (Item it in ifiles)
        { 
            _all.add(Item.getItem(it.Name
            , Vars.ImageDirectory + it.image
            , Vars.AudioDirectory + it.audio
            )); 
        }

    }

    #endregion

    #region public methods
    /// <summary>
    /// randomly generate an items pool for playback
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ItemsPool RandPresentation()
    {
        _presented = new ItemsPool();
        _presented = RandPool(_itemCount, _all);

        if (Vars.Randomize)
        {
            _displayed = new ItemsPool();
            _displayed = RandPool(_itemCount, _presented);
        }
        else
        { _displayed = _presented; }

        return _displayed;
    }
    ItemsPool RandPool(int count, ItemsPool pool)
    {
        ItemsPool rp = new ItemsPool();
        Item it = RandItem(pool);

        //get new randoms until we have enough
        do
        {
            //since only unique items may be added to an ItemPool,
            //we don't need to check if the the pool contains the random item
            it = RandItem(pool);
            rp.add(it);
        } while (rp.count < count);

        return rp;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// clear all, and start a new session
    /// </summary>
    public void startNew()
    {
        if (_timer.Active)
        { stopTimer(); }
        _sessCount++;
        _selected = new ItemsPool();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// decrement the session count
    /// </summary>
    public void decSessCount()
    {
        if (_sessCount > 0)
        { _sessCount--; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// log the results to the save file
    /// </summary>
    public void LogResults()
    { 
        if (_sessCount > 0)
        { logResults(); }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// add an item to the selected pool.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="it"></param>
    public void Selected(Item it)
    {
        _selected.add(it);

        if (_selected.count == _itemCount)
        {
            stopTimer();
            LogResults();
        }
    }

    private void stopTimer()
    {
        _timer.stop();
        timerStopped(this, new EventArgs());
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// remove an item from the selected pool
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="it"></param>
    public void remove(Item it)
    {
        if (_selected.Contains(it))
        {
            _selected.remove(it);            
        }
    }


    public void logSummary()
    {
        string[] lineSC = new string[_itemCount + 3];
        string lineF = "\t\t{0}\t{1}";
        string sumHdr1 = "\t\tPart\tN";
        if (RowPrefix.Length > 7)
        { 
            lineF = "\t{0}\t{1}";
            sumHdr1 = "\tPart\t\tN";
        }

        lineSC[0] = String.Format(lineF, RowPrefix, _sessCount.ToString());
        int ItemSum = 0;
        //go through each column, get the sum
        for (int i = 0; i < _itemCount; i++)
        {
            int cSum = 0;
            //go through the list and get the score results for this column
            foreach (int[] iarr in ScoreSum)
            {
                cSum += iarr[i];
            }
            ItemSum += cSum;
            lineSC[i + 1] = cSum.ToString();
        }
        //Mean Time
        double MTime = ((double)TimesSum / (double)_sessCount);
        MTime = Math.Round(MTime, 3);
        lineSC[_itemCount + 1] = MTime.ToString();

        //Mean Sum
        //double MSum = ((double)ItemSum / (double)_itemCount);
        //MSum = Math.Round(MSum, 3);
        //lineSC[_itemCount + 2] = MSum.ToString();

        //Sum
        lineSC[_itemCount + 2] = ItemSum.ToString();

        //create the header
        string[] sumHdr = new string[_itemCount + 2];
        sumHdr[0] = sumHdr1;
        for (int i = 0; i < _itemCount; i++)
        {
            sumHdr[i + 1] = "Itm" + (i + 1).ToString();
        }
        sumHdr[_itemCount + 1] = "M_Time\tSum";

        //put to file
        save.Append(dashBreak());
        save.Append(sumHdr);
        save.Append(lineSC);
        save.Append(dashBreak());

    }

    string dashBreak()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("|--------");
        for (int i = 0; i < _itemCount + 3; i++)
        {
            sb.Append("--------");
            if (i == _itemCount + 2)
            {
                sb.Append("-----------|");
            }

        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    #endregion

    #region private methods
    /// <summary>
    /// save the session's results to a text file
    /// </summary>
    void logResults()
    {
        //there should be a scoring method here and perhaps an option to
        //output scores instead of text options, but Susan did not want that.
        //added scoring 5/8/09
        int iCount = _presented.count;
        string[] score = new string[iCount + 2];
        int[] scs = new int[iCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < iCount; i++)
        {
            Item pre = _presented.getItem(i);
            Item sel = _selected.getItem(i);
            int sc = 1;
            //if (Item.Compare(pre,sel))
            //{ sc = 1; }
            if (pre.Name == sel.Name )
            { sc = 0; }
            score[i + 1] = sc.ToString();
            scs[i] = sc;
        }
        //log for the summary
        ScoreSum.Add(scs);
        TimesSum += _timer.Time;

        //create array for log file
        score[0] = String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", RowPrefix, _sessCount.ToString(), "errs");
        score[iCount + 1] = _timer.Time.ToString();

        //add the presented line
        save.Append(MakeRow(_presented, "pres"));
        //add the selected line
        save.Append(MakeRow(_selected, "sel"));
        //add the score line
        save.Append(score);
        //put an extra line in there
        save.Append("");
    }
    string[] MakeRow(ItemsPool ip, string prefix)
    {
        string[] row = new string[ip.count + 1]; // 2];
        row[0] = String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}",RowPrefix, _sessCount.ToString(), prefix);
        if (ip.count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ip.count; i++)
            {
                Item it = ip.getItem(i);
                row[i + 1] = it.Name;
            }
        }
        //row[ip.count + 1] = _timer.Time.ToString();
        return row;
    }
    Item RandItem(ItemsPool pool)
    {
        //setup a new random object
        Random r = new Random();

        /* the random generator has a fear of the last option,
         * so I'm giving it two chances to grab the last item... 
         * this may need adjustment.
         */
        int _play = r.Next(pool.count + 1);
        if (_play >= pool.count)
        { _play -= 1; }

        Item ri = pool.getItem(_play);
        return ri;
    }
    #endregion

    #region audio player methods
    void playItem(Item it)
    {
        player = new SoundPlayer();
        player.LoadCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(player_LoadCompleted);
        player.SoundLocation = it.audio;
        player.Load();
    } 
    void player_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (p_onset)
        { player.Play(); }
        else
        {
            player.PlaySync();
            if (!Vars.playOne)
            { PlayNext(); }
        }
    }
    int playQueue = 0;

    public void playLast()
    {
        int p = playQueue;
        if (p > 0)
        { p--; }
        playItem(_presented.getItem(p));
    }

    public void PlayNext()
    {

        if (playQueue < _presented.count)
        {
            Item it = _presented.getItem(playQueue);
            playQueue++;
            playItem(it);
        }
        else
        {
            playQueue = 0;
            _timer.start();
            if (p_onset)
            { 
                onset.Stop();
                onset.Enabled = false;
                onsetPlayFinished(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
    public void playOnset()
    {
        p_onset = true;
        onset = new System.Timers.Timer(Vars.onset);
        onset.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(onset_Elapsed);
        onset.Enabled = true;
        if (!Vars.playOne)
        {
            PlayNext();
            onset.Start();
        }
    }
    void onset_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Vars.playOne)
        { PlayNext(); }
    }


    #endregion

    #region events & handlers
    public event EventHandler onsetPlayFinished;
    public event EventHandler<StringEventArgs> TimerUpdate;
    public event EventHandler timerStopped;
    void _timer_Update(object sender, StringEventArgs e)
    { TimerUpdate(sender, e); }

    #endregion
}
```

}

My Code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Media;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using WMPLib;
    using AxWMPLib;

    namespace Memory
    {
/// <summary>
/// this handles the creation, tracking, and scoring of a single session
/// </summary>
class Session
{
    #region class Vars/Properties
    File save;
    ItemsPool _all, _presented, _selected, _displayed;
    initVars Vars = initVars.defaults;
    sessTimer _timer;
    System.Timers.Timer onset;
    bool p_onset = false;
    string _output = "Memdata." + DateTime.Now.ToString("Mdyy-HHmm") + ".txt";
    int _sessCount = 0;
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer  axWindowsMediaPlayer1;
    /// <summary>
    /// a collection of the sum of the scores for this session
    /// </summary>
    List<int[]> ScoreSum;
    /// <summary>
    /// the Sum of time results
    /// </summary>
    int TimesSum = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// the number of items to display
    /// </summary>
    int _itemCount;
    /// <summary>
    /// the number of items to display
    /// </summary>
    public int itemCount
    {
        get { return _itemCount; }
        set { _itemCount = value; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// the session count
    /// </summary>
    public int SessionCount { get { return _sessCount; } }
    string _prefix = "";
    /// <summary>
    /// the prefix for the Rows
    /// </summary>
    public string RowPrefix
    {
        get { return _prefix; }
        set { _prefix = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// the image width for each item
    /// </summary>
    public int ImgWidth { get; set; }
    ///<summary>
    ///video width for each item
    /// </summary>
    public int VidWidth { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// the max runs for this session
    /// </summary>
    public int maxRuns { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// debug value
    /// </summary>
    public bool debug { get { return Vars.debug; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// the onset value
    /// </summary>
    public int onsetValue { get { return Vars.onset; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// view Images before Audio
    /// </summary>
    public bool ViewImages { get { return Vars.ViewImages; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// allow correction 
    /// </summary>
    public bool AllowCorrection { get { return Vars.allowCorrection; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// play sounds one at a time
    /// </summary>
    public bool playOne { get { return Vars.playOne; } }
    #endregion

    #region constructors
    /// <summary>
    /// create a new session and load settings from an XML string or file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xml">either a path or a string of XML</param>
    /// <param name="SaveName">the name of the output file</param>
    public Session(string xml, string output, bool makeUnique)
    {
        if (output != "")
        { _output = output; }
        save = new File(_output);
        if (makeUnique)
        { save.MakeUnique(); }

        XDocument setupXML;
        //check to see if there are any XML nodes ie. is this a string of XML, or a path
        string fchar = xml.Substring(0, 1);
        if (fchar == "<")
        { setupXML = XDocument.Parse(xml); }
        else
        { setupXML = XDocument.Load(xml); }

        LoadXML(setupXML);
        //set some class vars based on the initial vars
        //these are variables that may change during the session
        _itemCount = Vars.Columns;
        ScoreSum = new List<int[]>();

        ImgWidth = Vars.width;
        maxRuns = Vars.maxRuns;

        _presented = new ItemsPool();
        _selected = new ItemsPool();

        _timer = new sessTimer();
        _timer.Update += new EventHandler<StringEventArgs>(_timer_Update);

    }
    void LoadXML(XDocument setupXML)
    { 
        // get the initial variables
        var initVars = from feed in setupXML.Descendants("var")
                       select new
                       {
                           Name = feed.Attribute("Name").Value,
                           Value = feed.Value
                       };
        foreach (var feed in initVars)
        { Vars.SetVar(feed.Name, feed.Value); }

        // parse the image and audio filename
        var ifiles = from feed in setupXML.Descendants("stim")
                     select new Item 
                     {
                         Name = feed.Attribute("Name").Value,
                         video = feed.Element("video").Value,
                         image = feed.Element("image").Value
                     };

        _all = new ItemsPool();
        foreach (Item it in ifiles)
        { 
            _all.add(Item.getItem(it.Name
            , Vars.ImageDirectory + it.image
            , Vars.VideoDirectory + it.video
            )); 
        }

    }

    #endregion

    #region public methods
    /// <summary>
    /// randomly generate an items pool for playback
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ItemsPool RandPresentation()
    {
        _presented = new ItemsPool();
        _presented = RandPool(_itemCount, _all);

        if (Vars.Randomize)
        {
            _displayed = new ItemsPool();
            _displayed = RandPool(_itemCount, _presented);
        }
        else
        { _displayed = _presented; }

        return _displayed;
    }
    ItemsPool RandPool(int count, ItemsPool pool)
    {
        ItemsPool rp = new ItemsPool();
        Item it = RandItem(pool);

        //get new randoms until we have enough
        do
        {
            //since only unique items may be added to an ItemPool,
            //we don't need to check if the the pool contains the random item
            it = RandItem(pool);
            rp.add(it);
        } while (rp.count < count);

        return rp;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// clear all, and start a new session
    /// </summary>
    public void startNew()
    {
        if (_timer.Active)
        { stopTimer(); }
        _sessCount++;
        _selected = new ItemsPool();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// decrement the session count
    /// </summary>
    public void decSessCount()
    {
        if (_sessCount > 0)
        { _sessCount--; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// log the results to the save file
    /// </summary>
    public void LogResults()
    { 
        if (_sessCount > 0)
        { logResults(); }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// add an item to the selected pool.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="it"></param>
    public void Selected(Item it)
    {
        _selected.add(it);

        if (_selected.count == _itemCount)
        {
            stopTimer();
            LogResults();
        }
    }

    private void stopTimer()
    {
        _timer.stop();
        timerStopped(this, new EventArgs());
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// remove an item from the selected pool
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="it"></param>
    public void remove(Item it)
    {
        if (_selected.Contains(it))
        {
            _selected.remove(it);            
        }
    }


    public void logSummary()
    {
        string[] lineSC = new string[_itemCount + 3];
        string lineF = "\t\t{0}\t{1}";
        string sumHdr1 = "\t\tPart\tN";
        if (RowPrefix.Length > 7)
        { 
            lineF = "\t{0}\t{1}";
            sumHdr1 = "\tPart\t\tN";
        }

        lineSC[0] = String.Format(lineF, RowPrefix, _sessCount.ToString());
        int ItemSum = 0;
        //go through each column, get the sum
        for (int i = 0; i < _itemCount; i++)
        {
            int cSum = 0;
            //go through the list and get the score results for this column
            foreach (int[] iarr in ScoreSum)
            {
                cSum += iarr[i];
            }
            ItemSum += cSum;
            lineSC[i + 1] = cSum.ToString();
        }
        //Mean Time
        //Same as original code
        //Mean Sum
        //same as original code

        //Sum
        lineSC[_itemCount + 2] = ItemSum.ToString();

        //create the header
        string[] sumHdr = new string[_itemCount + 2];
        sumHdr[0] = sumHdr1;
        for (int i = 0; i < _itemCount; i++)
        {
            sumHdr[i + 1] = "Itm" + (i + 1).ToString();
        }
        sumHdr[_itemCount + 1] = "M_Time\tSum";

        //put to file
        save.Append(dashBreak());
        save.Append(sumHdr);
        save.Append(lineSC);
        save.Append(dashBreak());

    }

    string dashBreak()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("|--------");
        for (int i = 0; i < _itemCount + 3; i++)
        {
            sb.Append("--------");
            if (i == _itemCount + 2)
            {
                sb.Append("-----------|");
            }

        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    #endregion

    #region private methods
    /// <summary>
    /// save the session's results to a text file
    /// </summary>
    void logResults()
    {
        //there should be a scoring method here and perhaps an option to
        //output scores instead of text options, but Susan did not want that.
        //added scoring 5/8/09
        int iCount = _presented.count;
        string[] score = new string[iCount + 2];
        int[] scs = new int[iCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < iCount; i++)
        {
            Item pre = _presented.getItem(i);
            Item sel = _selected.getItem(i);
            int sc = 1;
            //if (Item.Compare(pre,sel))
            //{ sc = 1; }
            if (pre.Name == sel.Name )
            { sc = 0; }
            score[i + 1] = sc.ToString();
            scs[i] = sc;
        }
        //log for the summary
        ScoreSum.Add(scs);
        TimesSum += _timer.Time;

        //create array for log file
        score[0] = String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", RowPrefix, _sessCount.ToString(), "errs");
        score[iCount + 1] = _timer.Time.ToString();

        //add the presented line
        save.Append(MakeRow(_presented, "pres"));
        //add the selected line
        save.Append(MakeRow(_selected, "sel"));
        //add the score line
        save.Append(score);
        //put an extra line in there
        save.Append("");
    }
    string[] MakeRow(ItemsPool ip, string prefix)
    {
        string[] row = new string[ip.count + 1]; // 2];
        row[0] = String.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}",RowPrefix, _sessCount.ToString(), prefix);
        if (ip.count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ip.count; i++)
            {
                Item it = ip.getItem(i);
                row[i + 1] = it.Name;
            }
        }
        //row[ip.count + 1] = _timer.Time.ToString();
        return row;
    }
    Item RandItem(ItemsPool pool)
    {
        //setup a new random object
        Random r = new Random();

        /* the random generator has a fear of the last option,
         * so I'm giving it two chances to grab the last item... 
         * this may need adjustment.
         */
        int _play = r.Next(pool.count + 1);
        if (_play >= pool.count)
        { _play -= 1; }

        Item ri = pool.getItem(_play);
        return ri;
    }
    #endregion

    #region video player methods
    void playItem(Item it)
    {
         axWindowsMediaPlayer1 = new AxWindowsMediaPlayer();
         axWindowsMediaPlayer1.PlayStateChange += new PlayStateChangeHandler(axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange);
         this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL ="it.video";
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
    } 
    void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (p_onset)
        { axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play(); }
        else
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
            if (!Vars.playOne)
            { PlayNext(); }
        }
    }
    int playQueue = 0;

  new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
   ...end of code block same as original
```